# LVM: How to recreate Volume Group after moving disks?

Tags: lvm

I had a volume group comprising of 2 x 1TB disks called **mirrorvg**

I had a single Logical Volume (**mirrorlv**) which used all available capacity (approx 1.82TB usable)

Because of some hardware problems I moved the disks to another system (same distribution)

When I interrogate the disks and LVM status it appears everything is as it was:

`vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               mirrorvg
  System ID

  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               1.82 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476932
  Alloc PE / Size       476932 / 1.82 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0

  VG UUID               Hfk5Vu-hAYY-dksV-y3nG-2rwM-sUMZ-PPWu05`

`lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/mirrorvg/mirrorlv
  LV Name                mirrorlv
  VG Name                mirrorvg
  LV UUID                LwLAQ5-OT0X-3q1m-7vlh-TlKl-OsyT-Rupf90
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time tvpc, 2015-09-11 16:24:07 +0100
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                1.82 TiB
  Current LE             476932
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto`

But if I try and mount the LV I get an error

`mount /dev/mirrorvg/mirrorlv /backup/
mount: special device /dev/mirrorvg/mirrorlv does not exist`

What do I need to do to get access to my data again? As you may have gathered I'm not that experienced in LVM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice the line `LV Status NOT available` in the output of `lvdisplay`?

Before you can access the volume group, you will need to activate the volume group using:

```
vgchange -a y
```

After the volume group is active you can mount the filesystem within the volume group.

Comment: Thanks - that worked! My brain went into panic mode, I should have paid more attention..